# How to split audio in dry and wet audio files if I have the dry version

Tags: audio, editing, sound-editing

Say I have the same vocal on 2 tracks one dry and one harmonized with Zplane veilklang 2 CM (the edition of Computer Music). I want to procces the main vocal differently from the harmonized copies of it.

How can I cancel out the dry from the wet on my proccesed track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could theoretically take the wet and dry tracks and drop them into a new session, invert the phase on the dry track, and then adjust the level on the dry track until it cancels out the dry component of the wet track, then bounce the result as your new wet track.

The easier way to go about it is to simply produce a wet track that is 100% wet, rather than being a partial wet/dry mix.

Comment: It's going to be fun lining up the wet and dry. The timing is messed up haha